# Kann man "einnehmen" oder "essen" in diesem Zusammenhang verwenden?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Ich möchte gerne sichergehen, dass dieser [Satz](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26973/how-to-say-that-i-like-to-eat-breakfast/26975#26975) richtig ist. Kann man sagen:

> Ich nehme das Frühstück ein.

Ich glaube, dass mein Satz formell klingt, oder?

Answer (score 2):

Genau so ist es, es klingt formell. **Der Satz ist aber richtig.**

Eigentlich heißt es ja generell „etw. zu sich nehmen“, etwa: »Der Nachmittagstee wird im Speisewagen eingenommen.«

In deinem Beispiel ist es sogar angebracht. Sonst müsste man nämlich sagen »Ich frühstücke« (ohne Substantiv) oder »Ich esse Frühstück« (was man nie sagen würde).

Siehe auch Bedeutungen und Beispiele [im Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einnehmen) oder [im DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=einnehmen).

Comment: Man benutzt bisweilen auch die Umschreibung: "Ich sitze am Frühstückstisch." (Da der Tisch als Gegenstand sich selten z. B. vom Mittagstisch unterscheidet, versteht man dann implizit, dass es sich um einen *für das Frühstück gedeckten* Tisch handelt, und der Sprecher es erwähnt, weil er dort isst.)

Comment: Niemand würde "ich nehme das Frühstück ein" sagen. "ich frühstücke" ist vollkommen in Ordnung, oder auch "ich esse mein Frühstück".

Comment: "Etwas einnehmen" verbinde ich persönlich mit Medikamenten, "etwas zu sich nehmen" dagegen eher mit Essen. "Frühstück einnehmen" klingt für mich falsch.

Comment: "Ich nehme das Frühstück zu mir" ist besser?